# How do I get the property of Kendo Mobile of checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a Kendomobile listview:

```
<li class="cycle">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="team3RedAssist">Assist Red</label>
</li>
```

I want to get whether it is checked and then be able to check it or uncheck it. On the web I can use something like:

```
$('#team3RedAssist').prop('checked');
```

to get the value. (or using attr) but for some reason this isn't working and using prop and attr to set it does nothing as well. I assume it is because of the styling, etc.

Comment: Is the `input` the definition on how to render each item of the list? Then you have as many `team3RedAssist` as items in the list but this is an `id` and should be unique.

Comment: It is a unique ID. Each list view element has a different ID.

Comment: Isn't `li` part of template for each item? if so, how is it possible that it is unique?

Comment: It is not part of a template. It is a static html list view.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are using remote binding and the checkbox in the template is still not created. Try to execute that logic inside the dataBound event of the listview.

Also using id inside template is not a good idea. There will be multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: It is a static html list view. I can't even get the value using Chrome console.  There is only 1 id

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In html page:

```
<div data-role="view" id="customers" data-title="My Data">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="MainListView">
     <li class="cycle">
         <label><input type="checkbox" id="team3RedAssist" />Assist Red</label>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document).body);      

    $('#MainListView').bind('click', function() {
           alert($('#team3RedAssist').prop('checked'));
    });

});
```

You could use above alert function wherever you want.

For online demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/2TkGR/8/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me (using jQuery prop): http://trykendoui.telerik.com/eYUg